# Good ways to import data into Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to import data into a Django project regularly. I need to tell the provider of my data what formats I want to received the data in. Should I ask for it in Json, XML, CSV ?

How does one usually deal with this in Django?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Django has a whole framework for importing data called Fixtures. You can read about the available formats (JSON is definitely there) here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

There are also examples of what the data should look like. Such as:

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
    }
  }
]
```

If you saved that as `beatles.json`, you could import it by running `python manage.py loaddata /path/to/beatles.json`

Comment: Awesome! Just what I needed. Now If I'm going to recieve data that doesn't necessarily match my Django Models, I assume that have to create a program that transforms the original JSON data into the appropriate JSON fixtures so I can then import to Django?

Comment: Yes, that usually isn't too difficult since you can parse the json, modify it as needed and spit out json using `json.load` and `json.dump`. If this answer satisfies you, please click the checkbox next to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: If the OP is loading *additional data* into a model with *existing data*, I don't think this is going to work. `loaddata` 1) *requires* the `pk` (primary key) field (there's no error checking), 2) bypasses any `.save()` processing. In a live system the next value of the `pk` is a moving target, so "guessing" it is not going to be easy. If you use the `pk` of an existing object *you will overwrite that object.*

Comment: Good point about the PK, but from the sound of it, he is getting data from his client to import directly to the DB

Comment: I actually do have existing data on my model, with this process I'm looking to regularly add more(about every week) data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support CSV or XML, I would advice to use [django-adaptors](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)