# Regularly uploading data to a Django site - fixtures or custom script?

Tags: django

Like the author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504585/good-ways-to-import-data-into-django), I have an existing Django web app and I want to upload new data to it regularly - once a month in my case.

I know that I could (as the previous answer suggests) transform my data into fixtures, then use Django's [in-built fixture support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/) to import it.

But this doesn't feel quite right - it isn't "initial" data, it's new data that will be uploaded regularly. Transforming it into fixtures feels like an unnecessary overhead, and the overall approach feels more suitable for initial data than for regular new data.

Currently I just have a Python script at the root of my project that parses the CSV file once a month and saves it directly into the database using the Django ORM. I run this once a month. Like this:

```
from models import Presentation

mydata = csv.DictReader(open('Jan2015.csv', 'rU'))
for row in mydata:
    p = Presentation(id=row['id'], name=row['name'])
    p.save()
```

This feels OK to me, but is there a better way / more Django-y way of doing things?

Comment: This is definitely the right way to do it. Even more so if you make this a Django manage.py command. As you say, fixtures are for initial or test data, not for ongoing updates.